# The options in "build task to run" aren't showed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, unreal-engine4

[PS:"When I tried to screen shot the menu above closes so I took a photo with my phone"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfosJ.jpg)

So I installed Visual Studio 2022 free version with the Game Development in C++ with Unreal option checked.

I installed the net sdk 3.1.

After that I installed the VS Code with C++ and Unreal Snippets extensions.

I changes the Source Code Editor in Unreal Engine with Visual Studio Code.

And it didn't work to select a "build task to run" version.

I tried to reinstall Visual Studio , the net sdk and the VS code.

I followed the tutorial again but no results.

What can I do?

-This is the log: https://github.com/JJPGdev/Log

-I use Windows 10.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to have both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2022 installed in order to use Unreal Engine.

For Visual Studio 2022, make sure you have the `C++ Profiling Tools` and `Windows 10 SDK` (10.0.18362 or newer). To add these go to `Tools->Get Tools and Features->Game Development with C++`

To build/compile your code, the easiest way is to click the compile button in Unreal Engine.

In Unreal Engine 5 this button is located on the very bottom menu. If you get an error, try clicking the 3 dots next to the compile button. Then, uncheck `Enable Live Coding` and try to compile again.

[image: Compile button UE5]

In Unreal Engine 4 this button is located in the menu above the viewport.

[image: Compile button UE4]